# Module parse failed when using Riot with Webpack, and Babel for es2015

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, riot.js

I have a project that is using ES2015 for the code, and also using Riot.
(The Riot components, however, do not need to be in ES2015, just old JS)
I am also using Webpack to build the project.

The problem I am getting is :

> "ERROR in ./src/test-tag.tag
>   Module parse failed:
>   .../tag-loader/index.js!.../riotjs-loader/index.js?{"type":"none"}!.../test-tag.tag
>   Unexpected token (5:18) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type."

It is complaining because of the way riot component script code looks, ie. a function must have just this for it's declaration `functionName() { /* the code */ }` , ie. there is no keyword `function`.

---

### Here is my full project

**app.js**

```
import 'riot';

import 'test-tag.tag';

riot.mount("*");
```

**test-tag.tag**

```
<test-tag>

    <h1>This is my test tag</h1>
    <button onclick{ click_action }>Click Me</button>

    <script>
         //click_action() { alert('clicked!'); }
    </script>

</test-tag>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <test-tag></test-tag>
    <script src="app_bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "riot_and_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015-riot": "^1.1.0",
    "riot": "^2.5.0",
    "riotjs-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "tag": "^0.3.0",
    "tag-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');
const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname + '/src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname + '/build'),
};



module.exports = {
    entry: [path.join(PATHS.src, '/app.js')],

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '.'], 
        extension: [ '.js' ] 
    },

    output: {
        path: PATHS.dist,
        filename: 'app_bundle.js'
    },


    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          riot: 'riot'
        })
    ],


    module: {

        preLoaders: [
          { test: /\.tag$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'riotjs-loader', query: { type: 'none' } }
        ],

        loaders: [

            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules)/,
              loader: 'babel', 
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
              }
            },

            { test: /\.tag$/, loader: 'tag' },
        ]
    }

};
```

---

Now - that will all work as expected, except that clicking the button does nothing because that code is commented out.
If the `click_action` line in `test-tag.tag` is uncommented, then `$ webpack` results in the error quoted at the top of this (horribly huge) question.

**Is there any way I can get webpack to accept the standard riot code?**
OR
**Is there a different way I can define riot internal functions in a way that webpack will not complain about?**

Comment: Did you ever solve this. I am trying to get riot generated code to work with webpack but can't get it done. Keep having warnings and errors in webpack generated code.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I did that project with the riot components only using an earlier version of JS. I would recommend avoiding that approach though, even if getting it to work correctly has a really great time cost.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kris, I found a blog somewhere that skipped the riot compiler and just generate the script. ES2015 allows multi line strings with ticks so the html template is easy enough to incorporate in your script. http://blog.srackham.com/posts/riot-es6-webpack-apps/ I'm trying the same strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that the "ES6 like" method syntax is something added by Riot, is not standard ES6.

This will be the standard js syntax

```
this.click_action = function() {
  alert('clicked!')
}
```

And this the es6 syntax

```
this.click_action = () => {
  alert('clicked!')
}
```

Also you have a typo in your button definition, it will be like this

```
<button onclick={click_action}>Click Me</button>
```